# Can agenda views be customized?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm working on an agenda file to organize my teaching each semester. I'd like to be able to view my agenda by semester. For example, my fall semester in 2017 will begin during week #2 and will end on week #18. Thus, I'd like to view my agenda starting from `Monday 9 January 2017` to `Sunday 7 May 2017`. Is this possible?

Comment: How about setting the variables `org-agenda-span` and `org-agenda-start-day`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up custom agendas of various types by using [custom commands](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html).  Basically you add a description of the agenda you want to view and settings for various options to the list `org-agenda-custom-commands`.

In this case, you want to set `org-agenda-start-day` to `"2017-1-9`" and `org-agenda-span` to `119` (that's 17 weeks * 7 days).  The code for your `.emacs` file is:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("S" "Semester Winter 2017"
               agenda ""
               ((org-agenda-start-day "2017-01-09")
                (org-agenda-span 119)
                (org-agenda-overriding-header "Semester Winter 2017")
                ))
)
```

Because a semester is a lot of days, this agenda will take some time to generate.

The entries in the list giving the custom command are:

1. A shortcut key using after `C-c a` to access the agenda.
2. A description.
3. The type of agenda (`agenda` in this case).  `agenda`, `todo` and `tags` are the most useful types.
4. For `tags` and `todo` types this is the tags or todo items to search for.  For the `agenda` type it should be an empty string.
5. A list of pairs `(variable value)` giving various settings to customize the agenda.